# Adding web facet to project without creating EAR

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to convert a java project to a dynamic web project programmatically by adding the required project facets.

Here is my code:

```
IProjectFacet JAVA_FACET    = ProjectFacetsManager.getProjectFacet("jst.java");
IProjectFacet WEB_FACET     = ProjectFacetsManager.getProjectFacet("jst.web");

iFacetedProject.installProjectFacet(JAVA_FACET.getVersion("5.0"), null, monitor);
iFacetedProject.installProjectFacet(WEB_FACET.getVersion("2.4"), null, monitor);
```

The facets get added correctly and the IDE recognizes the project as a web project. 
The problem I am seeing is that adding the facets also creates an EAR project which I don't want.

Is there a way to suppress creating an EAR and just adding the facets to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the creation of ear you can try this:

```
IProjectFacet JAVA_FACET = ProjectFacetsManager.getProjectFacet("jst.java");
IProjectFacet WEB_FACET = ProjectFacetsManager.getProjectFacet("jst.web");

iFacetedProject.installProjectFacet(JAVA_FACET.getVersion("5.0"), null, monitor);

IDataModel aFacetInstallDataModel = DataModelFactory.createDataModel(new WebFacetInstallDataModelProvider());
aFacetInstallDataModel.setBooleanProperty(IJ2EEModuleFacetInstallDataModelProperties.ADD_TO_EAR, false);

iFacetedProject.installProjectFacet(WEB_FACET.getVersion("2.4"), aFacetInstallDataModel, monitor);
```

In the same way, you are able to pass throw the same function a customize ear...